# how to force use of python 2.6_64bit in Mac OsX.6 for a single shell session?

Tags: python, 64-bit, bioinformatics

I'm trying to run the bioinformatics program Stampy, which requires the 64-bit installation of python 2.6. I can launch the 64-bit installation by typing

```
arch -x86_64 /usr/bin/python2.6
```

but when I run a Stampy command from within the shell, eg:

```
./stampy.py -G c_elegans.WS225.dna.fa
```

I get the following error:

```
Stampy requires a 64-bit Python install to run; 32-bit installations are not supported
```

I read here and on the OSX python manpage that the 64-bit installation should be available by default, but that doesn't seem to be the case here. I use the 32-bit installation for other things and don't want 64-bit to be the default. How can I force the use of this installation only when I am running this program?

Edit in response to @duskwuff:
I just tried all of these, which continue to give me the same error - except for the second option, which tells me x86_64 is not in my PATH. I have a 64-bit only installation in my PATH after the standard installation (looks like this):

```
#Setting PATH for MacPython 2.6_64
PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin/python:${PATH}"
export PATH
```

I know this version is actually 64-bit because if I launch python directly from within /usr/local/bin, the tests described here: http://asmeurersympy.wordpress.com/2009/11/13/how-to-get-both-32-bit/ give the 64-bit results.
I'm still very early in this learning curve - thanks for the help!

Comment: There's a typo in that second option: it should be `-x86_64`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a few solutions:

- You can run `stampy.py` with `arch`:

  ```
  arch -x86_64 ./stampy.py -G ...
  ```
- You can run `stampy.py` via `python` with `arch`:

  ```
  arch -x86_64 python stampy.py -G ...
  ```
- You can use the `VERSIONER_PYTHON_PREFER_32_BIT` environment variable:

  ```
  VERSIONER_PYTHON_PREFER_32_BIT=yes ./stampy.py -G ...
  ```
- You can set that variable for everything in the session:

  ```
  export VERSIONER_PYTHON_PREFER_32_BIT=yes
  ./stampy.py -G ...
  ```

Note also that Mac OS Lion (10.7) uses 64-bit Perl/Python by default.

Comment: Note that the `VERSIONER_PYTHON_PREFER*` options are an Apple-supplied modification to Python and only work with the system Pythons in OS X 10.6 and 10.7.

Answer (score 1):

You could edit `stampy.py` to directly invoke the system Python 2.6.  For instance, if there is a reference within the script (in the shebang line or elsewhere) to `/usr/bin/env python`, change it to `/usr/bin/python2.6`.